# Event Bus Subscrided event not calling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-event

I used the following code to communicate between the fragments of Tablayout. Produces the following error.

> No subscribers registered for event class MessageEvent
>
> D/EventBus: No
> subscribers registered for event class
> org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent

```
public class MessageEvent {
    
    
        private  int patientId;
    
    
        public  MessageEvent(int patientId){
    
            this.patientId = patientId;
        }
    
        public int getPatientId(){
    
            return this.patientId;
    
        }
    
    }
```

> ```
> Fragment1
> ```

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent(selectedPatientId));
```

> ```
> Fragment 2
> ```

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true,threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(MessageEvent event){

        Log.d("PatientID", "onEvent: " + event.getPatientId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before.

Try to create Singleton Class for EventBus.

Have a look at.

```
public class GlobalBus {

    private static EventBus eBus;
    public static EventBus getEventBus() {
        if (eBus == null)
            eBus = EventBus.getDefault();
        return eBus;
    }
}
```

In your Activity or Fragment initialize

```
GlobalBus.getEventBus().register(this);
```

Now post the event using SingleTon Class

```
GlobalBus.getEventBus().post(new MessageEvent(selectedPatientId));
```

And also don't forget to add proguard rules for a production build.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```